# Perform calculation in sencha touch Ext.XTemplate

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I need to display an Ext.Dataview using X Templates. The output should is based on some calculation of model properties. PFB the code.

```
Ext.define('lm.view.WaveList', {
extend : 'Ext.DataView',
xtype : 'waveList',
requires : [


        ],
config: {
    itemTpl:  new Ext.XTemplate('Hours Open {noOfHrsOpen/noOfHrsProjected}'),
    store: null,
    templateFile: null,
    style : 'background: white',
    pressedCls : '',
    selectedCls : '',
},

initialize: function(){
    this.callParent();


},


});
```

But the output is not based on the calculation {noOfHrsOpen/noOfHrsProjected} rather it just displays noOfHrsOpen

Any help.

Answer (score 0):

You can define functions within your Ext.XTemplate which you can use to achieve your goal.

```
var template = new Ext.XTemplate(
    'Hours Open: {[this.calculateOpenHours(values)]}',
    {
        calculateOpenHours: function ( values ) {
                return values.noOfHrsOpen/values.noOfHrsProjected;
            }
        }
    }
);
```

Take a look at [XTemplate](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.XTemplate) for further reading.